# a children's book about a boy and his dad who are actually aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens

the story is basically about an alien boy who lives with his dad as normal humans, tries to leave earth and crashes back to earth.(something goes wrong with their ship)

- I think they had come to earth to report back to their planet about life here
- the boy's surname is a name of a river in US, his teacher puts him with a another boy who also has a river's name as the surname.
- there was a fire in a barn... I can't remember the details :(
- the boy and his dad try to leave for their planet in a spaceship; the ship crashes; the boy is separated from his dad and hospitalized.
- at the hospital he doesn't speak properly...makes weird noises as far as i can remember...

I read this when I was small, so I can't remember that many details :( Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE!  Just one small thing - you aid you read this when you were 'small': could you add a year to that?  We love all the detail we can get here!

Comment: Hello and Thank you :) I read 'Space Race' (thanks @sueelleker) about a decade ago. So glad to find the name of the book!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be 'Space Race'- one of the Ormingat trilogy by Sylvia Waugh.

Comment: Please explain why this story is likely.

Comment: The boy's surname is Derwent, which is the name of a river, but that's all I can really add.

Comment: IT IS!! :D thank you, thank you! :) I'm so glad to finally get to the know the long-forgotten name! and I didn't know it was a trilogy, thanks for that information! :)